# neo4j multiple create cypher commands vs batch insert

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j and creating a node through cypher command.
 I followed movie Graph example where I can create multiple nodes and relationship in single command :

```
CREATE (TheMatrix:Movie {title:'The Matrix', released:1999, tagline:'Welcome to the Real World'})
CREATE (Keanu:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves', born:1964})
CREATE (Carrie:Person {name:'Carrie-Anne Moss', born:1967})
CREATE (Laurence:Person {name:'Laurence Fishburne', born:1961})
CREATE (Hugo:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving', born:1960})
```

Neo4j also gives batch operations API http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/rest-api-batch-ops.html. I want to build a library to create and update node and relationship, which option should I choose?

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: I want to build library in php or nodejs.

Comment: Don't use the batch endpoint, use the transactional endpoint, and there area already libraries, see http://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides